# Why does the for each loop keeps on adding the same item again and again to the collection?

Tags: .net, vb.net, loops, foreach

I have written this code but it keeps on adding only the last record multiple times. why?

It fetches loops on 10 times which is ok but only keeps on adding the last record to the collection? HOw would I do this? WHy does it add only last record?

```
  Public Function GetAllAsset() As AssetsDto()
        'Dim results() As Object = Me.Invoke("GetAllAsset", New Object(-1) {})
        'Return CType(results(0),AssetsDto())

        Dim v_ObjBREngine As VailPlantReports.BusniessRule.DataAccess
        Dim t_objUtil As New Utility

        Dim v_ObjConn As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MainConnectionString").ConnectionString

        v_ObjBREngine = New VailPlantReports.BusniessRule.DataAccess
        t_objUtil = New Utility
        v_ObjBREngine.SetCon(v_ObjConn)

        Dim v_ObjDs As New DataSet

        Try
            v_ObjDs = v_ObjBREngine.FetchSqlDS("select top(10) FunctionalLocation as 'TagNo', EquipmentDescription as 'TagDescription', Area as 'ParentHeirarchy', EqptType as 'TypeClass' from EngineeringData")

            Dim result As List(Of AssetsDto) = New List(Of AssetsDto)
            Dim dtTableFL As DataTable
            dtTableFL = v_ObjDs.Tables(0)

            'dtTableFL.Columns.Add("TagNo", GetType(String))
            'dtTableFL.Columns.Add("TagDescription", GetType(String))
            'dtTableFL.Columns.Add("ParentHeirarchy", GetType(String))
            'dtTableFL.Columns.Add("Class", GetType(String))

            Dim AssetsCls As New AssetsDto
            Dim AssetsClsArray As AssetsDto() = Nothing

            If v_ObjDs.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                'v_ObjDs.Tables(0).Rows.Add(v_ObjDs.Tables(0).NewRow())

                For Each Item In dtTableFL.Rows

                    AssetsCls.ASSETTAG = Item("TagNo")
                    AssetsCls.ASSETDESC = Item("TagDescription")
                    AssetsCls.PARENTTAG = Item("ParentHeirarchy")
                    AssetsCls.ASSETTYPE = Item("TypeClass")

                    result.Add(AssetsCls)


                Next

                AssetsClsArray = result.ToArray()

            End If
            Return AssetsClsArray
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try


    End Function
```

Comment: You've already been provided an answer to this question. You may have been asking about something else in that thread but this specific question was addressed in the answer provided there.

Comment: To be specific, the number of objects is determined by the number of times you invoke a constructor. If you debug your code as is, how many times is the `AssetsDto` constructor invoked? Now look at the code provided in the answer to your other question.

Comment: @jmcilhinney: I am asking that the list is filled with same rows ... the last row is getting repeated in all.

Comment: I know what you're asking and you already have your answer and I have explained why. Stop wasting your time and ours.

Comment: If you're going to ignore the answer to your question multiple times then you are, by definition, wasting your time and ours. If you think that it's rude to point it out when people do the wrong thing then you should probably avoid doing the wrong thing. I'm not calling you names or casting aspersions on your heritage. If we have to repeat ourselves multiple times because you don't read the information provided then don't expect "please" and "thank you".